# Unity: How do I restrict the character's position or velocity to an exact number, making it unable to go past that point?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

I'm still working on "perfect" ladder movement, and what I was able to come up with is a way to calculate the exact, specific distance the character needs to move while it is on the ladder to reach the point with which it will collide perfectly with the ground above the ladder.

I know this value is exactly specific because I allow my character to land on the ladder landing when the game starts (position.y = 3.6235), and when I print the movement value in the console I get exactly 3.6235.

I'm not sure that I'm implementing this correctly in code, though, as I've noticed that this value is still barely above "0" in the console once my character is all the way up the ladder. Is Mathf.Clamp() not the correct function to limit movement, or maybe I'm using it incorrectly?

```
public void ClimbUpLadder(ref Vector3 deltaMovement)
{
    float rayLength = raycastOrigins.centerRayLength * 2;

    RaycastHit2D[] hits = Physics2D.RaycastAll(new Vector2(raycastOrigins.center.x + deltaMovement.x,
        (raycastOrigins.center.y - raycastOrigins.centerRayLength + skinWidth) + deltaMovement.y), Vector2.up,
        rayLength, climbMask);

    Debug.DrawRay(new Vector2(raycastOrigins.center.x + deltaMovement.x,
        (raycastOrigins.center.y - raycastOrigins.centerRayLength + skinWidth) + deltaMovement.y), Vector2.up * rayLength, Color.green);

    for (int i = 0; i < hits.Length; i++)
    {
        if (hits[i])
        {
            if (hits[i].collider.tag == "Ladder")
            {
                IsClimbingLadder = true;
            }

            if (i >= 1 && hits[i].collider.tag == "platformOneWay")
            {
                //This gives us the exact distance needed to finish climbing
                GameObject platform = hits[i].collider.gameObject;
                Transform platformTransform = platform.GetComponent<Transform>();
                float finalMoveDistance = (platformTransform.position.y - characterTransform.position.y) + platformTransform.position.y;

                deltaMovement.y = Mathf.Clamp(deltaMovement.y, 0, finalMoveDistance);

                print(finalMoveDistance);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, after I set deltaMovement.y to this value it says that finalMoveDistance is around .9 or 1.0, so I still move slightly too far up the ladder. Do you think setting the character's transform.position.y directly is the best way to smooth out the movement? My goal is to eliminate any bounce when transitioning from climbing the ladder to walking on the ground again.

Comment: This might help you: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Lerp.html

Answer (score 1):

I think you're making a mistake here:

```
 float finalMoveDistance = (platformTransform.position.y - characterTransform.position.y) + platformTransform.position.y;
```

Why do you add the platformTransform twice?
Try this:

```
 float finalMoveDistance = (platformTransform.position.y - characterTransform.position.y);
```